# Ajax request with @form doesn't work when another form is on the page

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsf, liferay

I have the following script for a button in footer of my page, which will trigger an ajax request to show/hide a popup:

```
var updateState = function() {
        var footerDiv = $(".ui-footer").first();
        jsf.ajax.request(footerDiv, footerDiv, {
            render : "@form",
            execute : "@form",
            onevent : function(event) {
                if (event.type == "event" && event.status == "success") {
                    footer.initFooterButtons();
                    footer.ResizeAll();
                    footerDiv.trigger("reload");
                }
            },
            onerror : handleError
        });
    };
```

This works well. But when I add another form to the page (which is above the footer in the DOM), then the popup will not show/hide, instead the page gets reloaded. I guess it has to do with the `execute: "@form"`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Replace `@form` by the id of the form.

Comment: Please post your popup's code. Are you getting any javascript errors in the browser?

Comment: Sorry, I don't work on this project any more and have no longer access to the code.